# How to open a non standard port on windows azure virtual machine

Tags: networking, azure, windows-server-2008

I can't seem to figure this out and hoping someone can give me some pointers.  I'm unable to open a port on a Azure VM.  After a fresh provision of a Windows 2008 VM I've disabled the Windows Software Firewall for all networks.  Next i went to the azure management portal and added a TCP endpoint for port 9090 (both public and private).

While connected to the server via RDP i visit http://www.canyouseeme.org/ to test if port 9090 is open.  But it comes back as error cannot see the port 9090.

As far as I can tell this is a standalone VM not connected to any domains or special networks.

Any ideas what is missing?

Comment: when you went to that site (canyouseeme), did you actually see the public ip address of your server?

Comment: Yes, it was the public IP.

Answer (score 0):

This was a strange problem that i "fixed" by changing the VM size from extra small > small and back again.  For some reason something was reset and i could open the port again.

Comment: that looks strange, indeed : glad it's fixed